# Is it possible to scroll to a image map area?

Tags: jquery, html, area, imagemap, imagemapster

I'm stuck on this problem - I have 4 `img maps` below each other on single page. I have a [autocomplete search field](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) on top of the page and when typing string to search for, areas on every map are being highlighted.

Final step what I want to do is, when I select suggested word to highlight only 1 corresponding area (this is done) and to move (scroll) to this area. But I can't seem to get this working.

Every `area` has unique `id` like so:

```
<area id="1-1-5" href="#" alt="" shape="rect" coords="1103,103,1183,169">
<area id="1-1-7" href="#" alt="" shape="rect" coords="1207,103,1272,184">
<area id="1-1-2" href="#" alt="" shape="rect" coords="939,220,1019,286">
```

I hoped if I enter this `id` to `URL` (e.g. index.php#1-1-7), that it will jump to corresponding `area`, but it doesn't. I don't know if this is standard behavior for `img maps`, or if it's some sort of issue with [imageMapster](http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/), which I'm using for its awesome highlighting and tooltips over `areas`.

I also tried [jQuery `.scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) function, but with no luck.

If anyone has any idea how to make this possible, I'll be glad to try it out.

Comment: scrollTop should do what you want as long as this feature is beeing executed after any other movement scripts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567403/how-to-get-top-left-x-y-of-image-map-with-javascript-jquery for a discussion of retrieving scroll offset of image map polygons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Adrian Forsius and Palpatim I now have a working function, just what I needed. Thank you guys.

```
function findCoordinates(area_id){
    if (area_id != null && area_id != '') {
        var i, x = [], y = [];
        var c = $("area#" + area_id).attr('coords').split(',');
        for (i=0; i < c.length; i++){
            x.push(c[i++]);
            y.push(c[i]);
        }
        var t = y.sort(num)[0];
        var l = x.sort(num)[0];
        if (area_id.charAt(0) == '1') {
            t = parseInt(t) + 1350; // added height of 1st map
        } else if (area_id.charAt(0) == '3') {
            t = parseInt(t) + 2700; // added height of 1st and 2nd map
        }
//         alert( 'top = ' + t + ', left = ' + l );
        $(".image-maps").offsetParent().scrollTop(t);
    }
}

function num(a, b){
    return (a-b);
}
```